# How to make nutch plugin dependency jars available at runtime

Tags: java, plugins, ant, ivy, nutch

I am writing a nutch 1.7 plugin called entity-extractor, that depends on the [Stanford Corenlp](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/corenlp.shtml#Download) libraries.

Nutch manages dependencies with Ivy, so in my plugin source folder I have the following ivy.xml:

```
<!-- ./src/plugins/entity-extractor.ivy.xml -->
<ivy-module version="1.0" xmlns:maven="http://ant.apache.org/ivy/maven">

  ...

  <dependencies>                                                                                                                                                                                             
    <dependency org="edu.stanford.nlp" name="stanford-corenlp" rev="3.4.1">                                                                                                                                  
      <artifact name="stanford-corenlp" />                                                                                                                                                                   
      <artifact name="stanford-corenlp" maven:classifier="models"/>                                                                                                                                          
    </dependency>                                                                                                                                                                                            
  </dependencies>                            
</ivy-module>
```

In my plugin.xml, I specify that the plugin relies on these jars and their transitive dependencies:

```
<!-- ./src/plugins/entity-extractor/plugin.xml -->
<plugin>

  ...

  <runtime>
    <library name="entity-extractor.jar">
      <export name="*"/>
    </library>                                                                                                                                                                                             
    <library name="stanford-corenlp-3.4.1.jar"/>
    <library name="stanford-corenlp-3.4.1-models.jar"/>

    ...

  </runtime>
</plugin>
```

When I build nutch, both of these dependency jars, as well as the other dependencies, get copied to my plugin folder under ./runtime/local/plugins/my-plugin-name. Specifically, the folder contains the jar `stanford-corenlp-3.4.1-models.jar`, which doesn't contain any classes, but only tgz files containing the nlp models. In my code I can access the paths of the models inside the jar, via the [DefaultPaths](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/blob/master/src/edu/stanford/nlp/pipeline/DefaultPaths.java) class:

```
// yields "edu/stanford/nlp/models/ner/english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz"
String modelPath = DefaultPaths.DEFAULT_NER_THREECLASS_MODEL;
```

and when the models jar is in my classpath, I can access the files:

```
InputStream modelStream = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getSystemResourceAsStream(modelPath);
```

My problem is that this only works if I put the following into (nutch-source-home-dir)/ivy/ivy.xml

```
<!-- ./ivy/ivy.xml -->
<dependency org="edu.stanford.nlp" name="stanford-corenlp" rev="3.4.1">
  <artifact name="stanford-corenlp" />
  <artifact name="stanford-corenlp" maven:classifier="models"/>
</dependency>
```

And this doesn't feel like the correct way, since I already specify the jar dependencies in my plugin.xml and ivy.xml under my plugin source folder. In my code, I can look at the jars which the `SystemClassLoader` knows about:

```
ClassLoader cl = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();

URL[] urls = ((URLClassLoader)cl).getURLs();

for(URL myurl: urls){
    System.out.println(myurl.getFile());
}
```

And by inspection, my desired jars are available when I specify the dependencies in `./ivy/ivy.xml`, and not available when I don't. How can I tell nutch to make my jars available at runtime, without messing with `./ivy/ivy.xml`?